# Alternate way to install plugins in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, webmatrix

I am running wordpress on my local using Web Matrix. I am trying to install `"Types - Custom Fields and Custom Post Types Management."` plugin. But this is taking forever I am seeing message `"Installing Plugin Types - Custom Fields and Custom Post Types Management (1/1)"` from last one hour. The problem is I am not even getting error or installation fail notification. Anybody faced this kind of issue? and Is there any other way to install this plugin instead of doing it from UI available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Hi TolerantCoder,

if you are not able to install plugins from admin than you can download plugins from wordpress plugins Directory than extract zip file and add in you wordpress project plugins directory.

I.e: D:\wamp\www\citicollege\wp-content\plugins\ 

in plugins directory you can copy paste plugins and activate from admin.
```